# Unable to convert GeoPoint to Address

Tags: java, android

Im trying to reverse a GeoPoint object from its Lat and Long values to an actual string address.

So far, I pass the GeoPoint object to a method, the lat and long value are extracted, the address is stored in an array, the first address is set to a 'add' string variable and reutned to be set with an alert dialog..

This is show GeoPoint 'p' is sent and how the method is called:

```
String address = convertGpToLoc(point);

city.setText("Address: " +  address + "");
```

CityClickListner class:

```
class CityClickListener extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


    private GeoName geoName = null;

    CityClickListener(GeoName name) {
        this.geoName = name;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        Double Lattt = geoName.getGeometry().getLocation().getLat();
        Double Longgg = geoName.getGeometry().getLocation().getLng();
        updateMap(Lattt, Longgg); 

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        builder.setView(createView());
        builder.setTitle("Details of " + geoName.getName());

        builder.setCancelable(true);

        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   dialog.cancel();
               }
        });

        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }
```

convertGpToLoc method:

```
public String convertGpToLoc(GeoPoint p)
    {
        String add = "";
        try {

            Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(CityClickListener.this, Locale.ENGLISH);

            List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(
                p.getLatitudeE6()  / 1E6, 
                p.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6, 1);


            if (addresses.size() < 0) 
            {
               return null;
            }

            else
            {

                for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                {
                      add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                }

            }

        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {                
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return add;  

        }
```

LogCat:

```
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:120)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.location.GeocoderParams.<init>(GeocoderParams.java:50)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:64)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.example.restfulweb.PostalCodeAdapter$CityClickListener.convertGpToLoc(PostalCodeAdapter.java:207)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.example.restfulweb.PostalCodeAdapter$CityClickListener.createView(PostalCodeAdapter.java:175)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.example.restfulweb.PostalCodeAdapter$CityClickListener.onClick(PostalCodeAdapter.java:1 14)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-11 15:16:10.952: E/AndroidRuntime(304):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: CityClickListener probably isn't a real context. I guess you instanciate it yourself. Use your activity or the context of your view.

Comment: @njzk2 im extending an activity superclass for CityClickListner to provide my context. I will add the class.

Comment: yes, but an activty can be used as a context only if it is instanciated by the system, not by yourself. extends Activity just because you need a context doesn't work.

Comment: @njzk2 Many thanks for your comment. If the context of the activity is not what what do you suggest instead? The constructor accepts this context but as you say it looks like its not right.

Comment: according to your stacktrace, you have a view that calls the onClickListener. Use view.getContext() as context.

Comment: @njzk2 my getView method calls the onClickListener, but still the constructor willnot accept it

Comment: post what you have modified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); city =
>   addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1); country =
>   addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);

if some of them is null above, you will get nullpointer exception, because you havent used try catch in if block,

Use the code below,

```
 for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
     {
          try{  
              add += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {}
     }
```

Comment: I don't see what kind of exception you could be catching here. concatenation of null and string works, and neither `addresses` nor `addresses.get(0)` can be null at this point, given that it is accessed 2 lines above.

Comment: You are right, i thought there would be an exception, when concatenate null string. but while concatenating null string, java pars null value to "n,u,l,l" as string. So I am wrong i think.